# Get GridViewColumn from control inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listview, header, datatemplate, gridviewcolumn

Example:

```
<ListView Name="lvAnyList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="xx" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XX}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="yy">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YY}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If I access the `TextBlock` inside `DataTemplate` I will have access to information about the bound path.
But I don't know how to find (starting from the `TextBlock`) its containing `GridViewColumn` (which is in the `GridViewRowPresenter` columns list) and compare it to the grid's `GridViewColumn` (from `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` column list) to get the header's name.

At the end I should have the pairs: xx->XX, yy->YY

I can find a list of all `TextBlocks` inside `ListView` by using this:

```
GridViewRowPresenter gvrp = ControlAux.GetVisualDescendants<GridViewRowPresenter>(element).FirstOrDefault();
IEnumerable<TextBlock> entb = GetVisualDescendants<TextBlock>(gvrp);
```

I can find a list of all `GridViewColumnHeaders`:

```
GridViewHeaderRowPresenter gvhrp = ControlAux.GetVisualDescendants<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter>(element).FirstOrDefault();
```

And I cannot find the connection between the `TextBlocks` and the `GridViewColumns`...

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Did you find any way for this?? i am having same kind of issue and I've not got any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

GridViewColumns are abstract objects they never appear anywhere in the UI, you can try to name the column and bind it to the Tag of a control where you need it using `ElementName` or if that fails a `Source` with `x:Reference` on the name.

Comment: So there is no other connection between TextBlock inside DataTemplate to header name?

Comment: I at least do not know of any.